# How to secure SharePoint Shared SSRS Datasources

Tags: sql-server, security, sharepoint, reporting-services

I have a large reporting SharePoint site that contains about a dozen different shared data source connections, each one pointing at a different SQL server that is being utilized by the SSRS reports hosted on the site. Each data source has a cached account that is used to retrieve the data when a report runs so that report readers do not have to have read access to all of our SQL databases.

When someone with report building privileges creates a report, they are able to select one of the shared data sources hosted on the website, but then have to pass an authentication popup before they can actually write a query against the database:[image: Report Builder Query Authentication Window]

The strategy currently in use is that our authors do have read access to the SQL database and use that authentication (Use the current Windows user) to create the report and then when they save the report, readers utilize the account stored in the shared data source.  We then manage access to the data in the report through SharePoint security by only allowing people who should see that data to have access to the report.

**This seems all very standard to me...however**

I am able to query any database that any of the shared data sources have access to, regardless of my own permissions with a bit of rdl definition manipulation by following these steps:

1) Current account needs access to report builder and AD access to at least one SQL datasource (to make things easier)

2) Add a shared data source to the report that I have access to

3) Add a dataset with a query that follows this format SELECT '' as Field1 FROM DBNAME

4) Add a table to the report that simply displays Field1 from the query

5) Add one of the shared data sources that I should have no access to (there is no stopping me from adding the shared connection to the report, I simply am unable to use report builder to create a dataset using that data source)

6) Save report on the SharePoint site and then download a copy to local computer

7) Open rdl definition. Replace the data source for the SQL query with the name of the "unauthorized" data source (can delete original data source).  Replace the SQL query with one that queries the database for a list of table names (SELECT name as Field1 FROM sys.Tables)

8) Upload report definition back to SharePoint and run report

The report now uses the cached account and I've bypassed the nice authorization window that using report builder would have provided.  By using sys queries, I can find the databases, tables, columns and eventually the data without having to know anything about the database.  I could slow this method done by preventing access to the master database so that a list of databases can't be retrieved, but that's minor and not a complete solution.

Options:
- Could enforce security at the database level, however I don't want report readers to have permission against any of my source databases.  While each report could be fed from a view and then separately controlled to prevent access to anything more than what the report shows, this would be uncontrollable
- Force every report to use an embedded connection and not a shared connection. This would be hard to manage in the future when moving servers or when we need to know what reports are utilizing a specific connection (dependent items are available in the data source drop down menu)

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here as this seems to totally defeat the purpose of hosted, shared data sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantages of Shared Data Sources are administrative, in that they reduce the overhead in making changes to data source connection details such as passwords and server names. As you pointed out, using Shared Data Sources also allows you to easily identify dependent reports.

However Shared Data Sources are not a mechanism for securing data sources such as databases. Security really needs to be addressed at the database level to properly ensure only authorized people have access. If the credentials are stored in the report data source, then anyone able to access that data source or refernce it in a report is going to be able to execute queries on the connection.

I think the issue is in this step:

> 5) Add one of the shared data sources that I should have no access to
>   (there is no stopping me from adding the shared connection to the
>   report, I simply am unable to use report builder to create a dataset
>   using that data source)

There should be some way to prevent the report designers seeing shared data sources that they do not have permissions on. You might need to set individual permissions for each item, or put them in different locations to allow them to be secured with the correct permissions. I'm not a Sharepoint expert though so this is just a suggestion.

Comment: Yes, that would start to reduce the problem although we have a lot of connections that currently have access to multiple databases and we wouldn't want users to be able to see everything behind that shared connection.  The more I analyze the existing architecture, the more I realize it was built poorly; now it's just a matter of how do I even start cleaning it up :(